# Oracle Exadata - Compressing subpartition for query high and pctfree

Tags: oracle, exadata

How to compress only few subpartitions in partition, with `FOR QUERY HIGH` and `PCTFREE` option

My statement looks this:

```
alter table table_name move subpartition subpartition_name PCTFREE 10 compress for query high;
```

And this errors occurs after it:

```
ORA-14160:this physical attribute may not be specified for a table subpartition.
```

Answer (score 3):

Subpartitions are not independently compressible.

The 11gR2 documentation identifies the following portions of a heap-organised table as being compressible:

- For an entire table, in the physical_properties clause of relational_table or object_table
- For a range partition, in the table_partition_description of the range_partitions clause
- For a composite range partition, in the table_partition_description of the range_partition_desc
- For a composite list partition, in the table_partition_description of the list_partition_desc
- For a list partition, in the table_partition_description of the list_partitions clause
- For a system or reference partition, in the table_partition_description of the reference_partition_desc
- For the storage table of a nested table, in the nested_table_col_properties clause

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402

Comment: OK, but I can compress subpartition: 

alter table table_name move subpartition subpartition_name compress for query high; 

This statment works fine, but I can't put into PCTFREE parameter. Any ideas how to get around this problem?